# Should I use stack to build and upload to Hackage?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, hackage

Over time I've developed a messy system level Haskell installation that I'm [not sure how to completely clean up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41369064/656912). But for the most part this isn't of much concern as I simply use [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) to manage per-project Haskell configurations. However as my project requirements diverge from my system Haskell setup, I wonder what the best way is to build and upload packages for Hackage.

Specifically (1) should I be using

```
stack exec -- cabal sdist
stack exec -- cabal upload
```

instead of simply

```
cabal sdist
cabal upload
```

and (2) should is there any reason to install a project version of cabal (with `stack build cabal`?)

Or is there some better stack-based approach to building and distributing to Hackage that doesn't involve invoking `cabal` directly?

Comment: There is `stack sdist` and `stack upload` which I believe should work without invoking `cabal` directly.

Comment: It seems like `stack upload .` isn't seeing the credentials that `cabal upload` sees (I'm asked for my name, etc.). Any idea how to set those so I'm not asked each time?

Comment: From what I'm seeing it should save them automatically under '~/.stack/upload/credentials.json' ([in world-readable plain text](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2159)) after first upload.

Comment: @ppb: That seems to work, but after confirming that upload was successful I get "Environment variable GPG_TTY is not set (see man gpg-agent)" and "Unable to find gpg2 or gpg executable". [Any idea what's happening there?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41415900/656912)

Comment: @ppb: I think `stack sdist` and `stack upload` constitute an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding an answer based on my earlier comment.

---

`stack` offers equivalent functionality via its

- `stack sdist`
- `stack upload`

commands, which don't require interfacing with `cabal` directly in stack-based projects.

A full list of commands supported by stack can be obtained via:

```
$ stack --help
```

and the [official documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/stack/).

Individual commands also support `--help` to see what command line flags they support.