# GPG error when using 'stack upload'

Tags: haskell-stack, gpg-signature

When I run `stack upload` I get an error:

> Environment variable GPG_TTY is not set (see man gpg-agent)
>
> Unable to find gpg2 or gpg executable

The upload appears to succeed, but the error concerns me.

What are the consequences of this error? Is there a way to avoid to suppress it?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/05/stack-security-gnupg-keys
AFAIK signing packages is an optional, stack-specific feature, if you don't wish to do that you can pass `--no-signature` command line option to `stack upload`.

Comment: @ppb: That looks like an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion in the comments the errors are due to `stack` [trying to automatically GPG sign](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/05/stack-security-gnupg-keys) packages that are being uploaded [as of version 1.1.0](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/latest/ChangeLog/#110).

To my understanding this is a stack-specific feature (with no package signing built into `cabal` or hackage), and it can be disabled with `--no-signature` command line option to `stack upload`.